# Creating cumulative probability of winning in fantasy football league

Tags: r, probability

I'm in a fantasy football league with 12 teams, and through 6 weeks I have gathered all the winning scores:

```
w = c(148.70, 102.56, 170.92, 119.54, 95.62, 145.20, 126.32, 98.78, 78.62, 107.36, 146.46, 108.66, 162.56, 130.38, 103.72, 113.86, 138.04, 120.30, 139.90, 124.20, 115.08, 103.50, 153.00, 109.88, 103.28, 135.12, 115.32, 113.66, 158.12, 135.74, 128.64, 145.14, 105.70, 112.36, 98.60, 109.60)
```

and losing scores:

```
l = c(145.02, 81.86, 140.28, 62.96, 89.72, 112.60, 105.64, 74.42, 70.12, 100.72, 121.82, 95.90, 112.44, 89.88, 100.50, 99.54, 105.14, 107.80, 84.50, 118.38, 68.82, 92.70, 71.30, 86.90, 94.94, 89.44, 105.54, 99.44, 141.14, 98.30, 101.20, 105.90, 97.28, 76.82, 95.62, 66.62)
```

How can I produce a plot that shows the cumulative probability of winning depending on score e.g. approaching 0% below 78.62 (lowest winning) and approaching 100% above 145.02 (highest losing)?

For those unfamiliar with fantasy football, it's a head-to-head matchup every week.

Answer (score 0):

Using inbuilt function `ecdf()`

```
plot(ecdf(w))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect.